# Cannot browse Zend Framework project “Class 'Zend\Filter\AbstractFilter' not found ”

Tags: zend-framework, inflector

In my case i have added

C:\xampp\php

to my system variables and I edited include_path in php.ini file to

include_path=".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\xampp\htdocs\zf\library"

But when i'm trying to view my newly created project, it outputs this error.

Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Filter\AbstractFilter' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend_demo\library\Zend\Filter\Inflector.php on line 19

I have no idea since i'm new to Zend. Please help me out guys...

Comment: show the stacktrace and the code that throws the error

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up a stock standard ZF2 project, or made a clone of the ZendSkeletonApp? I'm assuming you're using Composer?